# connection string for mongodb with autoscaling in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a problem(or doubt) with a set of mongodb replicas hosted in kubernetes.
This is my part of my YAML that defines the set of replicas:

```
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 5500Mi
              cpu: 400m
            requests:
              memory: 1000Mi
              cpu: 200m
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--bind_ip"
            - 0.0.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 5500Mi
              cpu: 400m
            requests:
              memory: 1000Mi
              cpu: 200m
```

This successfully creates the set of three replicas. In addition to this the statefulset has a HPA(HorizontalPodAutoscaler) configured to create new replicas if needed. This is part of the HPA YAML:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-mongo
  namespace: mongo
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: mongo
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
```

this works fine. i have a nodejs application that communicates with mongodb, this is the connection string :

```
mongodb://mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017/webhook?replicaSet=rs0
```

now the problem. last week something happened in mongo that made node 1 unavailable, making node 2 the primary, which caused my nodejs application to fail to write to the db. the error:

```
Error in database: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: not primary
```

al revisar las replicas con rs.status() obtengo lo siguiente:

```
"members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 873188,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.003Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.002Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 2,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 234599,
                        "configTerm" : 6
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongo-1.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 874678,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.377Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.377Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 2,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 234599,
                        "configTerm" : 6
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 878592,
                        "optime" : {
```

my question is, how can I do to generate a dynamic connection string, since the statefulset at startup does it with three replicas, but if it scales it can be more.

I cannot simply add to the connection string:

```
mongodb://mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-1.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017/webhook?replicaSet=rs0
```

because it would be open the possibility that these three at some point are not available and pass to a fourth replica.

I was investigating and in a mongodb forum they stated that passing the parameter "replicaSet" to the connection string resolved all the host names automatically present in the replica, but this failed when changing node 1 from primary to node 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 1x available member from replicaSet on application startup , during runtime if you add more replicaSet members the application driver will find out automatically the others.
Since your hostnames seems to be predictable you may add in the URI at least 5 members , this is not a problem for the application since it will identify the avaialble members on startup automatically.

You will have permanent problem only if there is no available members on application startup.
During the incident you had it seems your PRIMARY lost connectivity to the others which trigers the election process to start between the available nodes and elect new PRIMARY.
The election process usually continue couple of seconds during which the replicaSet is in "READ ONLY" mode and if your application attempt to write during that time it will not be possible so you need to handle this error and attempt one more time after some seconds when there is new PRIMARY elected.

In general k8s microservices orchestrator is not best suitable for databases , but if you still need to be modern and keep it in k8s you need to be aware of the posible issues:

1. Sometimes when you write and there is issues to replicaSet is possible the writes sent to the lost PRIMARY to not yet be propagated to the SECONDARY elected as new PRIMARY. In case the old PRIMARY survive and return back to the replicaSet those writes will be removed from the collection and written to special folder called "rollbacks" , you need to check this folder manually and be ready to identify if they need to be taken in consideration.
2. You need to be ready to restore backups in case of serious failures affecting more then one nodes or caused by human mistakes. Restore backups the usual way via mongodump/mongorestore for big collections take some time respectively down time.
3. Sometimes if data is corrupted due to hardware failure or other you need to run special operations for recovery that are easier to be done offline.

Comment: Hi @R2D2 thanks for your answer. i understand what you mention, however, for the moment we will follow the k8s orchestrator to maintain our db until we move all this to mongodb atlas. so. from your explanation i summarize the following :

if i have three replicas i have to add these three to the connection string : mongodb://mongo-0,mongo-1,mongo-2/db?replicaSet=rs0

then, the other replicas created with autoscaling will be recognized by the application driver ?

Comment: or what you recommend me is to add to the connection string more host names, no matter if they exist or not ? example mongodb://mongo-0,mongo-1,mongo-2,mongo-3,mongo-4,mongo-5,mongo-6/db?replicaSet=rs0 and so when they are created with the autoscaling the application driver will know that it is already available to use ?

Comment: the driver can fetch the replicaSet configuration from any of the available members , so add to the URI the members you expect to have , if autoscaling is adding more later they are expected to be identified by the driver ...